# Vscode ... Unable to generate assets to build and debug. OmniSharp server is not running

Tags: visual-studio-code, debug, c#, build

I have a problem and searched over the internet and tried their solutions but nothing happend.

When i try to debug my code in VSCode , nothing happens.
I found in Debug menu there is no configuration , but I already have installed C# extensions.
then I tried the solution View > Command Palette > Generate Asset for Build and debug...
 I received this error `"Unable to generate assets to build and debug. OmniSharp server is not running."`
So any help please?
PS: Already downloaded the last version of mono because it was one of the solutions but didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I fixed it.

- Full uninstalled VSCode ( I had to delete some manually)
- Installed Again
- Installed C# Extension
- Add a workspace [File > OpenFolder] (Important One)
- [View > Command Pallete... > .NET: Generate Assets for Debug and Build]
- DONE!! , Now you can see in Debug panel [Ctrl+Shift+D] Debug: .Net Core Launch(Console) , Instead of "No Configuration".

Answer (score 1):

My Answer (Answer found on September 5, 2021) Tomorrow my Birthday

- Step one open Visual Studio Code
- Go to explorer or (Ctrl+Shift+E) to get there
- Open your folder that you created that you try to get Omnisharp into
- click on C# Program.cs, It should be the last one
- Then go to View (U can skip this step if u going to (Ctrl+Shift+P))
- Select Command Pattele or (Ctrl+Shift+P)
- From there it should bring up a Search bar
- Search  for OmniSharp
- Select "OmniSharp: Restart Omnisharp"
- Then wait for it to restart or agree to it to restart then wait
- Now then if u try to add what u going to add it should work :)

Hope this helps